# Image of boundary circle under map from punctured elliptic curve to ℂ

Tags: cv.complex-variables, riemann-surfaces

Let $E=\mathbb C/\Lambda$ be an elliptic curve,
and let $D\subset E$ be a very small disc.
($D$ is round for the usual flat metric on $E$)

By the main result of [1], there exists a holomorphic immersion $f:E\setminus D \to \mathbb C$.
 The image $f(\partial D)$ is a closed curve in $\mathbb C$ that self-intersects a bunch of times.

> What is the shape of $f(\partial D)$?

I understand that such a curve is not unique.
What I want is a qualitative description of an example of such a curve. A drawing would be great.

**Example:**
When $D\subset E$ is a "rather big" disk, the curve ⌘ is the image of $\partial D$ under an immersion $E\setminus D \to \mathbb C\mathbb P^1$ (points in the central square have two preimages; points in the four lobes have zero preimages). But that only works when $D$ is a rather big compared to the size of $E$, and I don't know how to modify this curve as the size of $D$ tends to zero.

---

[1]: Gunning, R. C., Narasimhan, R., Immersion of open Riemann surfaces. Math. Ann. 174, 103–108 (1967).

Comment: Neighborhood of the origin of $\mathbb{C}$ ? Take $U = \{s\in \mathbb{C}, s > r\}$ and glue  $U / \{ r e^{i t}= \infty e^{i t}\}$ to obtain a torus.

Comment: What do you mean by "shape"? This curve is not unique, what information about it you need?

Comment: @Alexandre Eremenko. That's right. The curve is not unique. I just want an example of what it can look like. @ reuns: The words "neighborhood of the origin" were confusing so I removed them.

Comment: Why does $f(\partial D)$ have to self-intersect? If you take $f$ to be (say) the Weierstrass P-function, and $D$ to be a sufficiently small disc around a point where $f'$ is nonzero, then $f(D)$ is homeomorphic to $D$ (ergo the boundary is a simple closed curve).

Comment: @Andre Henriques: I still don't understand the question: "what does it look like"? Can you be more precise? Do you want an example, or you want some general property of these curves?

Comment: @Andre Henriques: please also specify what is a "very small" disc. In what metric?

Comment: @Adam P. Goucher : The Weierstrass P-function is defined on the complement of the point $0\in E$, and has zero derivative at three other points. So it's not an immersion. Immersions have everywhere non-zero derivative on their domain of definition.

Comment: Let me try to rephrase my question as it is causing some confusion. Fix $\Lambda$. For every $\varepsilon >0$, let $\Sigma_\varepsilon:=(\mathbb C/\Lambda)$ \ {open disk of radius $\varepsilon$}. Pick a family of embeddings $f_\varepsilon:\Sigma_\varepsilon\to \mathbb C$ that varies continuously as $\varepsilon \to 0$. Can someone describe in qualitative terms what the family of curves $f_\varepsilon(\partial \Sigma_\varepsilon)$ can look like?

Comment: How do you define your embeddings $f_\epsilon$ ? A torus minus the neighborhood of one point  isn't simply connected.

Comment: @reuns A non-simply connected set can immerse to $\mathbb{R}^2$. For example, $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{ 0 \} \to \mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this is the kind of answer which will satisfy. Write $f$ for the function on $\mathbb{C} - \Lambda$ and $z$ for the coordinate on $\mathbb{C}$. Write $D^{\ast}$ for the punctured disc.

[Forstneric and Ohsawa](https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.0936) show we can take $f$ to be of finite order as $z \to 0$, meaning $|f| < \exp(z^{-N})$ for some $N$. Put $f' = g$, so $g$ is a nowhere vanishing function on $D^{\ast}$ and also of finite order. Let $k$ be the winding number of $g'$ as we travel around $0$, so $z^{-k} g$ has a logarithm on $D^{\ast}$, say $g = z^k e^{h(z)}$. Then $|h| < z^{-N}$ so $h$ is meromorphic. Say $h(z) = c z^{-n} + \cdots$.

Undoing the changes of variable, $f = \int z^k \exp(c z^{-n} + \cdots)$.

This integral has different behavior on the sectors where $c z^{-n}$ lies in the left or the right half plane. If we fix $\theta \in (0, \pi/2)$ and consider the $n$ wedges where $\arg(c)-n \arg(z) \in (-\theta, \theta)$, then we have an asymptotic series starting $- \tfrac{z^{k+2n+1}}{c (n+1)} \exp(c z^{-n})$. So, for $z = r e^{i \phi}$ with $\phi$ ranging through each of these wedges, $f$ swings around a circle of large radius, roughly $r^{-n}$ times.

Meanwhile, if $\arg(c)-n \arg(z) \in (\pi-\theta, \pi+\theta)$, then $f'$ is very small, so $f$ stays very near some limiting value. I don't know whether it is the same limiting value in the $n$ different wedges, I don't see why it should be. It circles that value roughly $r^{-n}$ times. However, I am not claiming that I understand the behavior near the $2n$ rays where $\arg(c)-n \arg(z) \in \{0, \pi \}$ well enough to subtract off these numbers of criclings from each other.

Comment: Very nice answer! Can any value of $\ell$ occur? Or do you think that $\ell$ is always equal to some fixed number?

Comment: I would expect it can be arbitrary since it is a lower order term than $N$. But I'll think about it a little.

Comment: My asymptotic analysis was broken: When $\mathrm{Re}(c z^{-n})$ is negative, I picked out the wrong dominant term. Will try to fix.

Comment: Fixed now (10 hours ago, actually).

Comment: I'm guessing that one can arrange to have $n=3$. Namely, that one can arrange for there to be exactly three limiting values ( where the curve is roughly stationary, and circles around a given point in the complex plane). This $n=3$ should be related to the fact that the genus is $1$ (for general genus, I'm guessing that one can arrange for $n=3g$). Is this something that you can see from your analysis?

Comment: I agree that $3g$ is a good guess. The proof in Forstneric and Oshawa goes as follows: Let $X$ be the closed Riemann surface, $X_0$ the punctured surface and $x$ the puncture. Find a nonvanishing $1$-form $\omega$ on $X_0$ -- when $g=1$, we can just take the global $1$-form from $X$. Then consider $\exp(f) \omega$ where $f$ ranges over holomorphic functions on $X_0$ of degree $\leq n$ at $x$. For $n$ large enough, they show that we can choose $f$ such that the $2g$ integrals of $\exp(f) \omega$ over a basis of $H_1(X_0)$ vanish. The $n$ for which this is true is the one we want. (continued)

Comment: The proof uses Runge's approximation theorem, which is hard to convert to concrete bounds. But, intuitively, Riemann-Roch tells us that the vector space of functions $f$ has dimension $n-g+1$. Replacing $f$ by $f+(\mathrm{constant})$ rescales the integrals, so that doesn't matter, so we are effectively choosing $f$ from a vector space of dimension $n-g$, and we want to make $2g$ integrals vanish. It is plausible that we can do this when $n-g =2g$ or $n=3g$. It would be fun to try and find solutions numerically in the $g=1$ case.

Comment: For $g>1$, the form $\omega$ may also have an essential singularity, and then the $n$ in question has to include the contribution from that. But this won't arise when we can take $\omega$ meromorphic, as we can in the $g=1$ case.

Answer (score 2):

Based on David Speyer's answer, I got what I want, namely some intuition about what these closed paths look like.
It's a bit hard to draw them, so I include an inline description.

---

Let $X:=3i$, $Y:=0$, $Z:=-3i$.
Given $T\in[0,\infty)$, I'll define a closed path in $\mathbb C$, which I'll call $\gamma_T$.

Let $R:=5e^T$ and $r:=e^{-T}$.
Let $C_X$ be the circle of radius $r$ centred around $X$.
Let $C_{Y}$ be the circle of radius $r$ centred around $Y$.
Let $C_{Z}$ be the circle of radius $r$ centred around $Z$.
Let $C_\infty$ be the circle of radius $R$ centred around $0$.

The path $\gamma_T$ is as follows:

> • Start at $Re^{-iT}$
>   • straight line to $X+re^{-iT}$
>   • run along $C_X$ for an angle of $4\pi+2T$, until the point $X+re^{iT}$
>   • straight line to $Re^{iT}$
>   • run along $C_\infty$ for an angle of $-2T$, until the point $Re^{-iT}$
>   • straight line to $Y+re^{-iT}$
>   • run along $C_Y$ for an angle of $4\pi+2T$, until the point $Y+re^{iT}$
>   • straight line to $Re^{iT}$
>   • run along $C_\infty$ for an angle of $-2T$, until the point $Re^{-iT}$
>   • straight line to $Z+re^{-iT}$
>   • run along $C_Z$ for an angle of $4\pi+2T$, until the point $Z+re^{iT}$
>   • straight line to $Re^{iT}$
>   • run along $C_\infty$ for an angle of $-4\pi-2T$, until the point $Re^{-iT}$

*Remark:* The path $\gamma_0$ is easy to visualise.
After deforming it a tiny bit, it becomes isotopic to the image of the curve ⌘ under the map $z\mapsto (z-a)^{-1}$, where $a$ is the middle point of one of the lobes.

---

I believe that there exists an elliptic curve $E=\mathbb C/\Lambda$ and an immersion $$f:E\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb C$$ such that $\forall T\in [0,\infty)$, the path $\gamma_T$ is the image under $f$ of a small counterclockwise loop (not quite round, but of bounded distortion) of radius $\simeq T^{-1/3}$ around the puncture.